# how to call same page for many times with differernt data should be displayed in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

page 1(yellow color): 5 buttons

page 2(blue color): information details

Am having page 1 with five button. After clicking each buttons, page 2 will be called. i want to call page 2 with different type of details should displayed.Find the screen shot. Here we can call seperate page for each button, i know that. But,apart from this can u tell me the other solution. Thanks for advance to all.
 [image]

[image]

Comment: have you know about how to pass intent data ? if yes then pass value which can be identified which button is pressed and base on show data in page 2.

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html, try something and tell use what is the problem your are facing.